# Regarding changes in UK residence card

Tags: united-kingdom, residence-cards

I got my UK residence card last April 2016 and due to marriage procedure, I need to have the surname updated.

For doing my civil ceremony procedure I decided to split my given name on old passport into a first name and surname in January 2017 and changed my old passport, it's not I changed my name completely to different name but I amend given name on the passport to first name and second name (surname).

When I was applying for UK resident card I had a different passport number and on my UK resident card has given a name and no surname. So presently passport has given name and surname and UK residence card has only given a name . I want to report this change to home office UK but exactly don't know how to proceed.

My problem is my marriage is in two months time in another country and is not in the UK, and I have other travel after marriage for 10 days and no time to get the replacement residence card.

How should I report this name and concern at immigration while traveling? I read that this change should be reported within three months.

Comment: Asha, Are you changing your name twice? Once from a single name into two, and now changing the surname again to your married name? I couldn't tell. I also tried to make the question more understandable. Please revert or comment if I misunderstood.

Comment: Thanks for the reply, no I am not changing name twice and after marriage, it will be the same name, as no surname on the passport, I change my old name in first name and surname, I mean split one given name into two for given name and surname.I did this I was getting complication in proceeding civil ceremony.

Comment: Where did you read this? Might be relevant